# Discord music bot won't join Voice channel

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord, discord.py

I followed a tutorial for creating a music bot in discord, but it will not join my vc no matter what. Every command works and it gives the correct responses and songs is in the queue. The bot have every permission know to man, but it still won't join. Any way to fix this issue?
Thanks in advance!!

This is my code and files

**main.py**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import asyncio

from help_cog import help_cog
from music_cog import music_cog

bot = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix="?", 
    intents=discord.Intents.all(),
    help_command=None
)

async def main():
    async with bot:
        await bot.add_cog(help_cog(bot))
        await bot.add_cog(music_cog(bot))
        await bot.start(os.getenv("TOKEN"))

asyncio.run(main())
```

**music_cog.py**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

from yt_dlp import YoutubeDL

import yt_dlp as youtube_dl

class music_cog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        self.is_playing = False
        self.is_paused = False

        self.music_queue = []
        self.YDL_OPTIONS = {"format": "bestaudio", "postprocessors": [{"key": "FFmpegExtractAudio", "preferredcodec": "mp3", "preferredquality": "192",}]}
        self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {"before_options": "-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5", "options": "-vn"}

        self.vc = None
        print("Success")

    def search_yt(self, item):
        with YoutubeDL(self.YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            try:
                info = ydl.extract_info(f"ytsearch:{item}", download=False)["entries"][0]
            except Exception:
                return False
        return {"source": info["url"], "title": info["title"]}

    def play_next(self):
        if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
            self.is_playing = True

            m_url = self.music_queue[0][0]["source"]

            self.music_queue.pop(0)

            self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(m_url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next())
        else:
            self.is_playing = False

    async def play_music(self, ctx):
        if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
            self.is_playing = True
            m_url = self.music_queue[0][0]["source"]

            if self.vc == None or not self.vc.is_connected():
                self.vc = await self.music_queue[0][1].connect()

                if self.vc == None:
                    await ctx.send("Could not connect to the voice channel")
                    return
            else:
                await self.vc.move_to(self.music_queue[0][1])
            
            self.music_queue.pop(0)

            self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(m_url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next())

        else:
            self.is_playing = False

    @commands.command(name="play", aliases=["p", "playing"], help="Play the selected song from YouTube")
    async def play(self, ctx, *args):
        query = " ".join(args)

        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if voice_channel is None:
            await ctx.send("Connect to a voice channel!")
        elif self.is_paused:
            self.vc.resume()
        else:
            song = self.search_yt(query)
            if type(song) == type(True):
                await ctx.send("Could not download the song. Incorrect format, try a different keyword")
            else:
                await ctx.send("Song added to queue")
                self.music_queue.append([song, voice_channel])

                if self.is_playing == False:
                    await self.play_music(ctx)
    
    @commands.command(name="pause", help="Pauses the current song being played")
    async def pause(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.is_playing:
            self.is_playing = False
            self.is_paused = True
            self.vc.pause()
        elif self.is_paused:
            self.is_playing = True
            self.is_paused = False
            self.vc.resume()

    @commands.command(name="resume", aliases=["r"], help="Resumes playing the current song")
    async def resume(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.is_paused:
            self.is_playing = True
            self.is_paused = False
            self.vc.resume()
        
    @commands.command(name="skip", aliases=["s"], help="Skips the currently played song")
    async def skip(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.vc != None and self.vc:
            self.vc.stop()
            await self.play_music(ctx)

    @commands.command(name="queue", aliases=["q"], help="Displays all the songs currently in queue")
    async def queue(self, ctx):
        retval = ""

        for i in range(0, len(self.music_queue)):
            if i > 4: break
            retval += self.music_queue[i][0]["title"] + "\n"

        if retval != "":
            await ctx.send(retval)
        else:
            await ctx.send("No music in the current queue")
    
    @commands.command(name="clear", aliases=["c", "bin"], help="Stops the current song and clears the queue")
    async def clear(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.vc != None and self.is_playing:
            self.vc.stop()
        self.music_queue = []
        await ctx.send("Music queue cleared")

    @commands.command(name="leave", aliases=["disconnect", "l", "d"], help="Kick the bot from the voice channel")
    async def leave(self, ctx):
        self.is_playing = False
        self.is_paused = False
        await self.vc.disconnect()
```

**help_cog.py**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class help_cog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        self.help_message = """
        Help message
"""

        self.text_channel_text = []
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        for guild in self.bot.guilds:
            for channel in guild.text_channels:
                self.text_channel_text.append(channel)

        await self.send_to_all(self.help_message)

    async def send_to_all(self, msg):
        for text_channel in self.text_channel_text:
            await text_channel.send(msg)
        
    @commands.command(name="help", help="Displays all the available commands")
    async def help(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(self.help_message)
```